# How to efficiently get value and attribute for each value in an enum?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

I want to get the value and an attribute for each value in an `enum`.

I know I can loop the values.

```
foreach (TEnum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
{
    MemberInfo? info = value.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
    if (info != null)
    {
        CustomAttribute? attribute = info.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();
        if (attribute != null)
            EnumLookup.Add(attribute.Code, value)
    }
}
```

But this seems horribly inefficient, having to call `GetMember()` and `GetCustomAttribute()` for each and every value.

If I used `GetMembers()` or `GetFields()` to get information for all the enum value, and then looped through them, it seems that would be more efficient.

```
FieldInfo[]? fields = typeof(TEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
{
    CustomAttribute? attribute = field.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();
    if (attribute != null)
        EnumLookup.Add(code, /* Whoops! What to put here? */ );
}
```

But then how could I get the value for each one?

Enums are strange because the values are like static fields, but there appears to be no way to get the value of a static field through reflection.

*Note: `EnumLookup` is a dictionary that maps a code (stored in `CustomAttribute`) to the enum value.*

Comment: Is your reflection code stored in a dictionary? So it's only being done once at the runtime if I understood you correctly?

Comment: @Mahmoud: I'm not sure what it means to store reflection code in a dictionary. I'm using reflection to *build* the dictionary. It's in a class, so if the class is static then it will only initialize the dictionary once. The problem is that I have a number of instances, and some of my enums have many values. So I'd like to be efficient.

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment, storing the Custom attribute types in a dictionary? what are you storing in a dictionary exactyl? Also `The problem is that I have a number of instances` number of instances of what exactly?

Comment: `my enums have many values` You mean many enumerations, many enum enumeration value and each has attribute on it??

Comment: @Mahmoud: The attribute contains a string value (like `DescriptionAttribute`) and I'm mapping that string value to the enum value (`Dictionary<string, TEnum>`). I have a class where each instance of that class manages such a dictionary. And I have a lot of instances of that class.

Comment: @Mahmoud: An enum with many values. Yes, each value has a custom attribute on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have some kind of store let's call it `EnumsAttributesStore` that scan your assembly only once at run-time and for each enum type `T` it calls on it `Enum.GetValues` and then it gets the custom attributes for that enum members.

After that, you expose one method `ResolveMemberValue<TEnum>(string memberName)` and all `EnumsAttributesStore` needs to do is to just lookup some kind of hash table `IDictionary<TEnum, (Attribute customAttribute, object value)`.

So that code is done only once at the runtime by scanning your assembly, after that the consumer of the code, all they need to do is to call your `ResolveMemberValue` or whatever you want to call it to get attribute or perhaps even value from an enum enumeration value.

So the idea basically is that since most of your work is actually static, you can do it only once at the runtime. But if you need to be more efficient that than, you have to deal with in a lower level, `IL` for example.

Or better, based on your last comment, seems you don't care about individual values for enums, you will need all values from certain enum type and you don't care about order. You could easily map in a dictionary of dictionary for example `IDictionary<EnumType, IDictionary<string,string>>`. You put in the type of enum, and you receive a hash map where the key is the individual enumeration name and the value is the value of attribute and all of that is done only once in your assembly load in the runtime.

Comment: As it is, I will only be building these tables once when they're first needed. It just seems like I should be able to loop through the members instead of looking up the members for each value. I need to map the attribute value to an enum, I don't want to map an enum to other dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that enum values behave like static fields. So I can enumerate the fields of my enum type. And to get the value of a static field, you just pass `null` to `FieldInfo.GetValue()`.

This saves me from having to call `GetMember()` every time through the loop.

```
FieldInfo[] fieldsInfo = typeof(TEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fieldsInfo)
{
    CustomAttribute? attribute = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();
    if (attribute != null)
        EnumLookup.Add(attribute.Code, (TEnum)fieldInfo.GetValue(null));
}
```

Unfortunately, with `nullable` enabled, it gives me a warning that the field value could be null even though it can't. Will work that issue next.